# Querying firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

If I want to get `EBpIvNpyXzYzog6BHcG9bJLgSGH2` and `Ghv13dLwkuR52HneS1nXmi2OznL2` using `addChildEventListener`, what should my query be in java?

this isn't working:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").addChildEventListener(object :ChildEventListener{
            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                val email= snapshot.child("email").value as String
                emails.add(email)
                snapshot.key?.let { keys?.add(it) }
                Log.i("abcd", snapshot.key.toString())
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code you tried that doesn't work the way you expect.  You can learn how to query Realtime Database using the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Does this line `Log.i("abcd", snapshot.key.toString())` print something in the logcat? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo No it doesn't, I need the code to get the uuid(string of random numbers and integers)

Comment: Have you also tried to log the error `Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage())` in `onCancelled()`? Is there something over there printed out?

Comment: @AlexMamo No I am not getting any error too. I need code to get `EBpIvNpyXzYzog6BHcG9bJLgSGH2`

Answer (score 0):

```
String user_id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();   
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(user_id).child("email");
```

This will retrieve the `"email"` of the currently logged in user.

Comment: I asked for the uuid not email

Comment: then get the value of it and convert it to a string

Comment: What I meant was, I want `EBpIvNpyXzYzog6BHcG9bJLgSGH2` from database